# Panel floats over GWT DialogBox

Tags: html, css, gwt

I need one of my gwt Panels to be always above all other content and always accessible for user to click on it's elements.
Even if there is a DialogBox opened on page my Panel should flow over it. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

With a `PopupPanel` you should be able to set the z-index CSS property to a large-ish number that will place it in front of any other floating panels (including `DialogBox`)

```
popupPanel.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(100);
```

Comment: I tried. But even though panel is over all other elements, it's content refuses to answer to mouse interactions when DialogBox opened